# JavaScript- update the contents of an HTML <p> tag when the cursor hovers over an image on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have an HTML5 canvas on which a number of images are displayed. I have drawn the images to the canvas using a local copy of the KineticJS library (I'm using a local copy as I wanted to change the functionality it provides slightly).

I now want to write a function that will update the text displayed in an HTML `<p></p>` tag when the cursor is detected as hovering over a particular image that I have displayed on the canvas.

The function I have written looks like this:

```
function cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY){
if((mouseX >= assetsDescriptionBox.img_x && mouseX <= assetsDescriptionBox.img_x + assetsDescriptionBox.img_width) &&
    (mouseY >= assetsDescriptionBox.img_y && mouseY <= assetsDescriptionBox.img_height))
    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[34];
}
```

`mouseX` and `mouseY` are global variables, and I have defined the variable `assetsDescriptionBox` using the line

```
var assetsDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("assetBox");
```

'tipsParagraph' is the ID of the paragraph whose innerHTML I am trying to replace, and `tips[34]` is an element from a JS array that contains the text I want to display in the paragraph

"assetBox" is the ID I gave to an image that has been included in the hidden section of my HTML. The image is displayed on the canvas as intended, however, whenever I hover the cursor over that image, I get a console error telling me that "assetsDescriptionBox is not defined"...

I can't work out why this is... haven't I declared it with the line `var assetsDescriptionBox = ...`? The line it's complaining about is the 'if' statement in my `cursorOverAssetsBox` function.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit**

It also appears that adding the call to `cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY);` in the `_mousemove` function in the Kinetic.js file has stopped it being possible to drag and drop the images around the canvas- any ideas why this is?

The `assetsDescriptionBox` variable has been defined in the following function:

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(){
console.log("function drawDescriptionBoxes() is drawing the description boxes");
var assetsDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("assetBox");
var liabilitiesDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("liabilitiesBox");
    var incomeDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("incomeBox");
var expenditureDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("expenditureBox");  

drawBox(assetsDescriptionBox, 70, 400, 120, 70);
drawBox(liabilitiesDescriptionBox, 300, 400, 120, 70);
drawBox(incomeDescriptionBox, 530, 400, 120, 70);
drawBox(expenditureDescriptionBox, 760, 400, 120, 70);

}
```

This function is in a separate JS file, called "drawdescriptionboxes.js", and has been added to the head of my HTML file with the line `<script src="drawdescriptionboxes.js"></script>`

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The order and position of your declaration of `assetsDescriptionBox` is important. Can we see a little more code?

Comment: Sure, will add it in now.

Comment: Code to show declaration of `assetsDescriptionBox` has been added.

Comment: Your code looks fine--just make sure you have an element with an ID of `assetBox` on the page when you declare `assetsDescriptionBox`, and don't call this function until the DOM has loaded.

Comment: It also would probably be easier to load the image with `new Image()` instead of using the DOM for this purpose...

Comment: I'm just thinking- it's the first line of the `cursorOverAssetsBox` function that the console is complaining about... The `cursorOverAssetsBox` function is in another separate JS file, called tips.js- this has also been included in the index.html file in the same way as the drawdescriptionboxes.js file, although it is included after the drawdescriptionboxes.js file in terms of order- should I move it to be included before drawdescriptionboxes.js?

Comment: Ah--of course, I see your issue now. I didn't realize you were trying access `assetsDescriptionBox` from another function. You have two options to fix this issue--either redeclare `assetsDescriptionBox` inside `cursorOverAssetsBox` or make it a global variable. Personally, I'd suggest nothing more than copy/pasting your declaration of `assetsDescriptionBox` to `cursorOverAssetsBox`. If this solves your issue I'll write up an answer detailing why.

Comment: Hey, thanks- doing that has got rid of the console error I was getting, however, the text in the paragraph is still not updated when the cursor hovers over the image. Any ideas why that's not happening, and how I would make it happen?

Comment: How are you calling `cursorOverAssetsBox`? In a `mousemove` event?

Comment: Yes- I'm calling it with the line: `cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY);` inside my `mousemove` function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25708/discussion-between-elliot-bonneville-and-someone2088)

Comment: Anyone else have any other ideas?